# Code Igniter Inheritance error

Tags: php, codeigniter

Well i  have defined a derived class from CI_Controller known as application  that is present in the `system/core/`folder

```
<?php

Class Application extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

} 

?>
```

and derived an class from application named as home which displays the home page

```
<?php


Class Home extends Application {


  function __construct() {
     parent::__construct();
  }

  public function index() {

     $this->load->view("Home");

  }

} 

?>
```

But i still get an error saying that Class 'Application' is not found

Comment: Are you using namespaces? check out http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: Could you try moving the Class Application from system/core to application/core

Comment: Here is the user guide link http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html and http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html#extending-core-class

Comment: Name it `MY_Application.php` and set it within `APPPATH.'core'` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Change core class name from 'Application' to 'MY_Controller'(class name must ends with _Controller) and save it as MY_Controller.php

```
Class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

}
```

Then extend the application controller class

```
Class Home extends MY_Controller {
```

You can use any words instead of MY_. For this change the following line in config.php

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
```

Make sure only Uppercase letters are allowed.